# Power query - strategy for handling repeating rows

Tags: powerquery, m

Given a report which as a table with **repeated row headings**, is there a good strategy for using Power Query/M to extract the data in a clean format?

For example the report available [here](https://www.opec.org/opec_web/en/publications/338.htm), has an excel file (which at time of writing is pointing to August 2021):
https://www.opec.org/opec_web/static_files_project/media/downloads/publications/MOMR%20Appendix%20Tables%20(August%202021).xlsx

In this example:

- we have the World demand table portion
- Non-OPEC Liquids production portion
- both of these have rows: Americas/Europe/Asia Pacific:

[image]

- which makes it hard to distinguish them in Power Query
  [image]

What is right approach which would allow extraction of data from this type of table?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a column ... custom column ... with formula

```
=if [2018] = null then [Column] else null
```

and then right click the new column and fill down

That would put World Demand and non-OPEC as a column that you could additionally filter on